# NSDictionary SQLite mapping

Tags: database, sqlite, nsdictionary

I need to map my database IDs with NSDictionary or NSArray. 
I have a table view. When I'm clicking by some field - must apear a details view in which will be detailed information about record.
All work ok, when:
DB   TableRow
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3

But whem 
DB   TableRow
1 -> 1
30 -> 2
31 -> 3
don't work.

So I need to link with each other database record and table view. Any suggestion? Thanx!

Comment: Show the lines of code where you are passing from your table view to your detail view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    detailTableView = [[DetailsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"DetailsTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    //getting selected row
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 


    //initializing detailTableView with data to show details
    [detailTableView setWithObjectID: [[usersIDList objectAtIndex: row ] intValue] ];

    //show it
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailTableView animated:YES];
    [detailTableView release];  
}
```